# outofmemory Exception when Deserializing

Tags: asp.net

I am sending data asynchronous over TCP after serializing it and when receiving data and call the `binaryformatter.deserialize`

> I got outofmemory Exception.

Please can someone help me finding the issue?

```
private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(List<DataEvent> obj)
    {
        obj = null;
        obj = new List<DataEvent>();
        obj.Add(new DataEvent("tag1", "1", DateTime.Now,"good",    DateTime.Now));
        //obj.Add(new DataEvent("tag2", "2", DateTime.Now, "good", DateTime.Now));
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }



 private static Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var obj = binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you getting the exception. Some bit of stack trace would help

Comment: i am getting exception while calling the deserialize.var obj = binForm.Deserialize(memStream); Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: Do you debug it ? Is arrBytes != null ?

Comment: yes arrBytes is not null.